# Device Details Tracking Android Management API (MDM)

Tags: android-management-api, android-enterprise

We are Performing POC To get all the device information after device provisioning Like Battery Status, Geo Location, Available storage and many more

By using Android Management API

As we were able to get so many information from Custom DPC

Comment: Tried Policies.StatusReportingSettings.PowerManagementEventsEnabled  but  getting device.PowerManagementEvent is null

Comment: Hello aakash, are you setting up a work profile or a fully managed device? It's expected that this feature doesn't work on work profiles.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable these flags in your policy :

```
{
  "applicationReportsEnabled": boolean,
  "deviceSettingsEnabled": boolean,
  "softwareInfoEnabled": boolean,
  "memoryInfoEnabled": boolean,
  "networkInfoEnabled": boolean,
  "displayInfoEnabled": boolean,
  "powerManagementEventsEnabled": boolean,
  "hardwareStatusEnabled": boolean,
  "systemPropertiesEnabled": boolean,
  "applicationReportingSettings": {
    object (ApplicationReportingSettings)
  }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#statusreportingsettings

After enabling these flags when you call enterprises.devices.get you will get the reports in response.

```
"networkInfo": {
    object (NetworkInfo)
  },
  "memoryInfo": {
    object (MemoryInfo)
  },
  "memoryEvents": [
    {
      object (MemoryEvent)
    }
  ],
  "powerManagementEvents": [
    {
      object (PowerManagementEvent)
    }
  ]
```

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#resource:-device

Note: Geo locations are not yet available in reports.

Comment: We have enabled all status reports but some are still missing, specifically `networkInfo` in my case. Our devices have SIMs in them. Unsure why these details are missing.

Comment: I would suggest to deploy a device admin client to the devices and fetch all the data through that client. It will be more reliable and you will have more control